# Progress dialog not showing in button click event in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, progressdialog, onclicklistener

I have a button in each list item of list view. In that button click event i have some codes to run. In click event  im showing the progress dialog before the code runs. but its not getting shown. After all the codes in click event completes in the end progress dialog gets shown. Plz help me.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    TheListViewM = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    ImageAdapter anImageAdapterM =new ImageAdapter(this);
    TheListViewM.setAdapter(anImageAdapterM);

}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContextL;

    public ImageAdapter(Context contextP) {
        mContextL = contextP;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return ItemList.GetLength();
    }

    public Object getItem(int PositionP) {
        return ItemList.GetObject(PositionP);
    }

    public long getItemId(int PositionP) {
        return PositionP;
    }

    public View getView(final int PositionP, View ConvertViewP, ViewGroup ParentP) {



        if (ConvertViewP == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContextL.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ConvertViewP = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_cart_row_layout, ParentP, false);
        }
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) ConvertViewP.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        textView1.setText("asdfg");
        final Spinner spQuantity = (Spinner) ConvertViewP.findViewById(R.id.spQuantity);

        spQuantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> Parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {


                    ProgressDialog aProgressDialogL = new ProgressDialog(mContextL);
                    aProgressDialogL.setMessage("Loading...");
                    aProgressDialogL.show();

                    //Processiing codes
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> QuantityAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContextL,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, QuantityList);

        QuantityAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spQuantity.setAdapter(QuantityAdapter1);

        Button btn1 = (Button) ConvertViewP.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            ProgressDialog aProgressDialogL = new ProgressDialog(activity1.this);

                            aProgressDialogL.setMessage("Loading...");
                            aProgressDialogL.show();        }
                    });

                    return ConvertViewP;
    }
```

Comment: Any exceptions ? or try to create the progress dialog like this     ProgressDialog aProgressDialogL = new ProgressDialog(mContextL);

Comment: no exception, i will try mContextL....

Comment: @RajeshCP mContextL didnt work.....

Comment: It would have been better if you post th entire code ?

Comment: use `ConvertViewP.getContext()` instead of `activity1.this`. put the full code of your adapter

Comment: @RajeshCP Yes..I have deleted that...

Comment: @Vignesh Please post the code that will execute when the an event triggers...Because it that code blocks the UI thread then progress dialog won't display until it completes

Comment: @RajeshCP i posted entire code.... both in spinner and button progress dialog displays only after finishing "//Processiing codes"

Comment: @Pragnani im calling soap call in async task, which is long set of code, that  y i gave like //Processiing codes

Comment: @Vignesh you can set the progress dialog in the asynctask it self...No need to kept it in the button cilck

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContextL;

public ImageAdapter(Context contextP) {
    mContextL = contextP;
}

public int getCount() {
    return ItemList.GetLength();
}

public Object getItem(int PositionP) {
    return ItemList.GetObject(PositionP);
}

public long getItemId(int PositionP) {
    return PositionP;
}

class ViewHolder {
    Button btn1;
    TextView textView1;
    Spinner spQuantity;
}

public View getView(final int PositionP, View ConvertViewP, ViewGroup ParentP) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (ConvertViewP == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContextL.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ConvertViewP = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_cart_row_layout, ParentP, false);
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) ConvertViewP.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.spQuantity = (Spinner) ConvertViewP.findViewById(R.id.spQuantity);
        holder.btn1 = (Button) ConvertViewP.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        ConvertViewP.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) ConvertViewP.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView1.setText("asdfg");

    holder.spQuantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> Parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {


                ProgressDialog aProgressDialogL = new ProgressDialog(mContextL);
                aProgressDialogL.setMessage("Loading...");
                aProgressDialogL.show();

                //Processiing codes

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> QuantityAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContextL,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, QuantityList);

    QuantityAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    holder.spQuantity.setAdapter(QuantityAdapter1);


               holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        ProgressDialog aProgressDialogL = new ProgressDialog(activity1.this);

                        aProgressDialogL.setMessage("Loading...");
                        aProgressDialogL.show();        }
                });

                return ConvertViewP;
}
}
```

Comment: try to edit your question instead of posting your code as an answer

Comment: first, try to display a simple `Toast` in `onClick()` of the button or a `Log.d("onClick", "button "+position+" clicked");` and test if it works ,

Comment: @Houcine ya same problem, toast also displaying at the end of all codes.

Comment: @Houcine View holder class is missing.once again am edit your code.

Comment: @Vignesh View holder class is missing.once again am edit your code.Till you didn't get means say i gave tutorial link.

Comment: @Vignesh am edited but I don't know where it is, there is some network problem in my side I think.Wait I post again.

Comment: @Vignesh now am edit in my answer see that one you get some idea.